# How do you access the roles of the currentItem from a listview in QML?

Tags: listview, roles, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I'm trying to access a role from a ListView in QML.  Essentially, I have this in my QML:

```
ListView {
    id: myId
    model: myModel
    delegate: Item {
        Text {
            text: model.text
        }
        Text {
            text: model.moreText
        }
    }
}
```

`myModel` is a QAbstractListModel implementation.  The QML portion of this is a reusable component, so the model could have any number of different roles with various data types.  What I would like to do is bind to the value of a given role of the `currentItem` property of the ListView.  In other words, I'd like to have some other `Component` on the page that could bind a property to the currently selected item in the ListView as follows:

```
Text {
    text: myId.currentItem.text // Or myId.currentItem.model.text (or something similar)
}
```

Please keep in mind that I need this generically available, as I'll be doing this a lot for a number of model types and I'm trying not to write that kind of custom code for each model and ListView.

It seems like it should be simple to access a property of the currently selected item, but as far as I can tell it is not possible.  The problem is complicated further by the fact that models appear to be treated differently when there is only one role.  By this I mean that sometimes you access your roles via `model.roleName` whereas when there is only one role you use `modelData`.

If anybody has any suggestions, I would truly appreciate it.  Thanks so much!

**EDIT**

I found this:

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.qml/1778

However, this doesn't appear to work for me.  I'm getting type errors when I try to use the data in my QML scripts, and there is no type casting available so I'm not sure what to do.  Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The code at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.qml/1778 should work, although I do see errors if the property is named 'data'; it looks like it is overriding some existing built-in property. Renaming it to 'myData' seems to work:

```
ListView {
    id: myId
    model: myModel
    delegate: Item {
        property variant myData: model
        Text {
            text: model.text
        }
        Text {
            text: model.moreText
        }    
    }
}

Text { text: myId.currentItem.myData.text }
```

(The *myId.currentItem.text* code in the original post didn't work because this was trying to refer to a *text* property within your delegate, which didn't exist.)

In regards to referring to *model* vs *modelData* within the delegate, the difference depends on the type of the model, rather than the number of roles in the model. If the model is a string list or object list, *modelData* is used to refer to the individual string or object from within a delegate (since string lists and object lists do not have any roles). For all other models, including the QML ListModel and the Qt C++ QAbstractItemModel, *model.role* can be used to refer to a role within a delegate.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response!  Hmm... I thought tried this exhaustively, but there may be some nuance I've missed.  It's nice to know it is working for somebody though!  I'll give this solution a go again and see if that does the trick.  I appreciate the clarification between model.role and modelData.  I'll let you know how things turn out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like it does work.  Not sure what I had been missing before.  Either way, this solution took hours to find so hopefully now that it's on StackOverflow other people will be able to find it quickly.  Thanks again!

Comment: Is there any way to abstract over the different model types ? I'm asking because I'd like to handle a QML ListModel during testing and an object list in the C++ application using the same QML code.

Comment: Any idea on getting this same approach working with a ComboBox? There is no `currentItem`...

Comment: Nice. I didn't have to alias the "model" as such, but adding property properties to the ListView delegate allowed me to query the values from eg "onCurrentIndexChanged" handler.

Answer (score 5):

You could alternatively access the model directly, with something like

```
Text { text: myModel[myId.currentIndex].text }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Answer (score 3):

You can access a ListElement of ListModel using get() function.

```
Text { text: myModel.get(myId.currentIndex).text }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone myModel is the Model which you will provide to the ListView and myId is the listView and text is is a role. For example `ListModel {
    id: myModel
    ListElement {
        text: "Apple"
        cost: 2.45
    }
    ListElement {
        text: "Orange"
        cost: 3.25
    }
    ListElement {
        text: "Banana"
        cost: 1.95
    }
}
 ListView {
        id: myId
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: Text { text: text }
    }`

Comment: Is this supposed to work even if the model is defined in c++? Because I can't seem to make it work. It says that property get is not defined.

Comment: @Savvas What is the type of your C++ model?

Comment: It's a QAbstractList stored in an SQL db.

Comment: `get()` is a ListModel method. I haven't tested this solution with QAbstractList. You may have to use `QAbstractItemModel::roleNames()` in some way. Check [QAbstractItemModel Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#public-functions)

Comment: I thing, that if you have own C++ model, you must create own funciton get - in model. I have same problem...