# How to access data in QML TableViewColumn delegate?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5.1

How to access the current item in a `TableViewColumn`?

```
TableView {
    id: atcTableView
    model: myatclist
    ...
    TableViewColumn {
        ...
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        id: atcTableViewColFreq
        role: "frequency"
        title: "Frequency"
        width: 120
        delegate: Component {
            Text {
                text: "Freq is " + currentItem / model / model.frequency
            }
        }
    }
```

As of this similar question " [How do you access the roles of the currentItem from a listview in QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5231882/356726) " I have tried all kind of combinations `model`, `modelData` , `currentItem`, and something like `model.role`.

If I remove the delegate entirely, frequency displays correctly. Model is based on `QAbstractListModel`. Any hints?

Btw, can I see in QML debugging what properties are available in a delegate?

-- Edit based on Kakadu's comment --

```
        delegate {
            Text {
                text: "freq is " + frequency
            }
        }
```

gives me: `ReferenceError: frequency is not defined`

Comment: I have not work with TableView columns but intuition says that you should try `frequency` in you Text element. Sorry if my guess will not work

Comment: Updated details above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
delegate: Text { text: view.model.get(styleData.row).frequency }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use styleData.value:

```
delegate: {
   Text { text: styleData.value }
}
```

It's described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop) (look for itemDelegate property)

Comment: Please specify a clear question. We don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Yow must to define the role in te QAbstractItemModel.

> QHash YourClassModel::roleNames() const {
>
> ```
> roles[Qt::UserRole + 1] = "frequency";
> return roles;
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Will try, and provide feedback