# QML ListModel and custom function property

Tags: qml, qt5, qt5.2

I want to write tuned version of TableView (TableView.qml in Qt package). 
I have *ColumnDescriptor.qml* with column definition:

```
Item {
    property string title
    property var formatDelegate: null

    .... (other property definition)

    function format(val) {
        if (formatDelegate != null)
            return formatDelegate(val);
        else
            return val;
    }
}
```

The above code defines set of properties and fuction `format(val)`, that calls for format value if `formatDelefate` was set.

In the main table I use *list* to store predefined columns definition (temporaly) and *ListModel* to store final columns definition ( the latter is more useful than *list* in remaining implementation)

*list* example:

```
 property list<ColumnDescriptor> colDefines: [
    ColumnDescriptor { 
        title: qsTr("col1")  
    },
    ColumnDescriptor { 
        title: qsTr("col2")
        formatDelegate: function(val) { return "!" + val}
    }
]
```

Filling *ListModel* (`id: columnModel`):

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    for(var i = 0; i < colDefines.length; ++i)
    {
        var col = colDefines[i];
        ...(some calculation)
        columnModel.append(col);
    }
}
```

All looks fine, but when I try to call *format* from model item, Qt sends me the following error

```
Property 'format' of object QQmlDMListAccessorData(0x8e3bf78) is not a function
```

Example of calling *format*:

```
Repeater {
    model: columnModel
    Text {
        text: model.format([SOME USEFUL DATA])
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if I call *format* directly from *list* it works well. 
So my question here is how to fill model in a way that the *format* or other function will work correctly when being called from model?

Comment: This is pretty much a mystery to me, and I don't understand why getting data back from a list is so difficult in QML. You may, however, find this useful (I did): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5239864/1858225

Answer (score 0):

For QtQuick2 this should work

```
formatDelegate = [function(val) { return "!" + val}]
formatDelegate[0]("some text")
```

but you could also use an overriding technique:

```
Item {
    function formatDelegate(val) {
       return val;
    }

    function format(val) {
       return formatDelegate(val);
    }
}
ColumnDescriptor { 
    function formatDelegate(val) {
       return "!" + val
    }
}
```

This way Item.format() should call "return val" as default and "!"+val for ColumnDescriptor given that ColumnDescriptor is derived from Item.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Repeater {
    model: columnModel
    Text {
        text: columnModel[index].format([SOME USEFUL DATA])
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this early and retried today - not work (with same error)